# Using a proxy for a GAE python application

Tags: python, google-app-engine, proxy

I'm browsing a website with https://code.google.com/p/gaemechanize2/ and it works quite well. However when I do it from appspot.com it's not working as expected. I supposed the web server sees it's not coming from the same country or something else and change its behaviour. To check that, I'm trying to use a proxy (from my host) but it does not work for the hosted application. It works when I use the local gae application but not when I push it to Google. Has anyone succeeded in using a proxy for a GAE application ? It seems it always uses default system settings :(

FYI I'm using the following code :

```
from gaemechanize2 import _mechanize
url="http://www.google.fr"
br = _mechanize.Browser()
br.set_proxies({"http": "myuser:mypassword@my_proxy_ip:my_proxy_port"})
br.set_handle_robots(False)
br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Firefox')]
br.open(url)
```

Thanks